# Explore SQLite database and its relationships

Tags: sqlite

What is a good software or solution to explore my .sqlite databases on OS X?

I'm currently using SQLite Database Browser 2.0, but it's kind of sparta.
I'd like to have the chance to also explore the relations between my entities and stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a large [list of management tools](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools) at SQLite's site. I usually use [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/).

Comment: thx, I chosed SQLiteStudio that was the only option for OSX, it's way better than SQLite Database Browser